# Keyboard hiding behind compose popup android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-softkeyboard, android-popupwindow, android-compose-textfield

I have created a popup in jet pack compose android which is attached with screen bottom and taking inputs.
Using popup() jetpack component.
But as soon as I focus on text field keyboard is opening but it’s behind the popup. I am not sure why keyboard is not coming on front..

Comment: you mean , you have TextField in Popup  which is aligned in bottom and when you focus on textfield , it hides behind the pop up right ?

Comment: I will suggests you instead of popup , you can use Dialog or AlertDialog